# Layout for seminar paper; justified, font, size, spacing

Tags: fonts, spacing, fontsize

I just started university and decided to graduate from Word for writing my papers, thesises and so on.

But I have some problems with probably the most simple things... I got this template:
[here the template](http://zil.dhbw-karlsruhe.de/wiki/index.php/LaTeX/Vorlagen)

and I have to change the layout to the following criteria:

DIN A4
Margin: left: 2.5cm, right: 3cm, top: 2.5cm, bottom: 2.5cm
Font: Serif font for example Times New Roman
Size: 12pt, 10pt for tables, footnotes etc.
Spacing: 1 1/2 and 1 in footnotes
Text has to be justified.

```
% Präambel
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,
liststotoc, % Tabellen- und Abbildungsverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
bibtotoc, % Literaturverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis aufnehmen
titlepage, % Titlepage-Umgebung statt \maketitle
headsepline, % horizontale Linie unter Kolumnentitel
%abstracton, % Überschrift beim Abstract einschalten, Abstract muss dazu in {abstract}-Umgebung stehen
DIV12, % auskommentieren, um den Seitenspiegel zu vergrößern
%BCOR6mm, % Bindekorrektur, die den Seitenspiegel um 6mm nach rechts verschiebt,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{ucs} % Dokument in utf8-Codierung schreiben und speichern
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % ermöglicht die direkte Eingabe von Umlauten
\usepackage[english]{babel} % deutsche Trennungsregeln und Übersetzung der festcodierten Überschriften
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Ausgabe aller zeichen in einer T1-Codierung (wichtig für die Ausgabe von Umlauten!)
\usepackage{graphicx} % Einbinden von Grafiken erlauben
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Einstellung der verwendeten Schriftarten
\usepackage{textcomp} % zum Einsatz von Eurozeichen u. a. Symbolen
\usepackage{listings} % Datstellung von Quellcode mit den Umgebungen {lstlisting}, \lstinline und \lstinputlisting
\usepackage{xcolor} % einfache Verwendung von Farben in nahezu allen Farbmodellen
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl} % zur Erstellung des Abkürzungsberzeichnisses
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Zusatzpaket zur Gestaltung von Fuß und Kopfzeilen
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} % Hier die Seitenränder einstellen
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
%\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-\topskip}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-1.1cm}} % Vertikalerabstand top
```

I used geometry to set the site layout to DIN A4 and to set the margins. For the 1 1/2 spacing I used \onehalfspacing. In the documentclass I have got 11pt because 12pt look far too big...
For a serif font I used \fmfamily.

Are this changes correct? How do I use justified text and how can I use a font with the right size as in 12pt/Times New Roman in Word?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Could you check and fix the link?

Comment: In LaTeX, text is automatically justified. You would have to tell LaTeX explicitly, not to justify, for example by \raggedright, \raggedleft or \center.

Concerning the font size: If the criterion is 12pt, then use 12pt, not 11pt. If you want to use Times New Roman, I recommend using `xelatex`, which lets you use any font your operating system provides.

Comment: `\usepackage{mathptmx}` to load Times New Roman font. Pass the option `12pt` to your document class. You're doing the right thing regarding interline spacing: `\usepackage{setspace} \onehalfspacing` will give you a spacing of 1.5 in normal text but will maintain a spacing of 1 in footnotes.

Comment: !@ClaudioFiandrino oh sorry forgot to use hyperlink. corrected it. !@Toscho Thank you. Good to know that it is already justified. !@Jubobs Thank you too. Again good to know that the footnote will be 10pt if the font size is changed to 12pt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're halfway there. The following code should do what your require. See the comments in my code for explanation.

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
% The "12pt" class option sets \normalsize to 12pt and \footnotesize to 10pt.
% If not modified, the font size in footnotes will correspond to \footnotesize.

\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathptmx}   % loads Times New Roman
\usepackage{setspace}   % for interline spacing
\onehalfspacing         % interline spacing of 1.5 in main text, 1 in footnotes 

\usepackage{lipsum}     % dummy text

% Here, I redefine \tabular to automatically switch to
% \footnotesize within the scope of a tabular environment.
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\renewcommand{\tabular}{\footnotesize\oldtabular}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo bar}

An outline of intellectual rubbish%
\footnote{Man is a rational animal, so at least I have been told.
    Throughout a long life, I have looked diligently for evidence
    in favour of this statement, but so far,
    I have not had the good fortune to come across it.%
}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    hello & see ya & bye\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Foobar}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is code made it really easy to understand what you mean. :)